# How to center Data URI in background image?

Tags: css

It seems that background-position/background-cover is not working with data URI as background images? What I have is a preview of images to be uploaded. To show those previews I am using JS to get the data URI into CSS background images, which I hope to center.

But I notice the following code does not work with a data URI

```
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: block;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRg...);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7pfc2vLx/

**UPDATE**

I notice like many mentioned I am missing background-position in my above example. But seems like even with that it does not work when its an inline style?

```
<div id="profile-avatar" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; background-position: center center; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAA
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7pfc2vLx/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something in your question, but shouldn't you just add the position?

```
background-position: center;
```

Comment: I notice even with this it does not work as an inline style? In update:  https://jsfiddle.net/7pfc2vLx/4/

Comment: It looks like it's working to me, that image is a square so it's already centered via the `background-size: cover` style.

Comment: It does, but that's how it should look, right? The image is a square, so it will be centered inside the square div. Look here for a couple more examples: https://jsfiddle.net/7pfc2vLx/6/

Comment: It shows the entire image because of `background-size: cover`. This will make the image scale at proportion until it fills all of its container's height and width; since the container is square, all of the image is shown. If you don't want the image scale to change in that way, set `background-size:100%` (or whatever scale you prefer).

Comment: Oh now I understand, theres a piece of code that resizes the images to a square ...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to Center an image then try [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7pfc2vLx/1/)

```
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgEASABIAAD/4QBsRXhpZgAASUkqAAgAAAAD…y5eKCQaVqJ0y7W7JJJ2b6cxwd3MlGwz9mN4vrwL6sTjY+BzMiXWzjSpa2fJRFOu/auHjYv/9k=);
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: For some reason, when used in an inline style, its not working? https://jsfiddle.net/7pfc2vLx/4/

Comment: @JiewMeng why you are assigning width to it? And make background-size: contain.

Comment: Hmm, cos I want to limit the size of the image?

Comment: try   background-size: 200px 200px; and background-position: center center;

Answer (score 0):

Your background already fit the div and if you want to make sure it's in the centre of the div, add:

```
background-position:center center;
```

But seem nothing change, because your div is not center itself, so add:

```
margin:0 auto;
```

Now they all in center posistion. https://jsfiddle.net/7pfc2vLx/2/

Comment: I notice even with this it does not work as an inline style? In update: jsfiddle.net/7pfc2vLx/4. I dont need the image to center with `margin`